# How to change value for item in a list of dict in python in a simple way?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Suppose a list composed by several dict in python:

```
a = [{1: u'100'}, {2: u'200'}, {3: u'300'}]
```

I'd like to change the datatype of items of the dict from unicode to float, i.e.,

```
a = [{1: 100.0}, {2: 200.0}, {3: 300.0}]
```

The following are my current codes:

```
for i in a:
   for j in i.keys():
       if type(i[j]) == unicode:
           i[j] = float(i[j])
```

It works but I hate this stupid expression.
There must be some much more elegant expression.
Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> a = [{1: u'100'}, {2: u'200'}, {3: u'300'}]
>>> [{k:float(v) for k,v in d.iteritems()} for d in a]
[{1: 100.0}, {2: 200.0}, {3: 300.0}]
```

If you need to add a Unicode type check, you can, but then arguably a nested list/dict comprehension isn't all that readable any more:

```
>>> a = [{1: u'100'}, {2: u'200'}, {3: u'300', 4: "not unicode"}]
>>> [{k:float(v) if isinstance(v, unicode) else v for k,v in d.iteritems()} for d in a]
[{1: 100.0}, {2: 200.0}, {3: 300.0, 4: 'not unicode'}]
```

Comment: Any hints / tutorials to learn such pretty expression? I used c before.

Comment: The `[...]` one is a list comprehension, and inside it the `{...}` bit is a dictionary comprehension. They are very similar, one builds a list and one builds a dictionary. Python documentation introducing them is here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions